# Limiting floats to reduce data size

Tags: python, formatting

I use `round()` to limit the float to `n` decimal points, but the data that I have has a lot of values that can be reduced.

For example:

```
0.0 to 0  
-0.0 to 0  
0.12 to .12  
-0.12 to -.12  
1.0 to 1
```

How that can be done using python?

Comment: What data size?

Comment: The size of a floating point number does not depend on the number of decimal positions.

Comment: The data is printed and saved into a file.

Comment: And why do you need to reduce the size of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x="""0.0
-0.0
0.12
-0.12
1.0
12.0
-12.00
12.001
-12.001
10.01
-10.01
00.12"""

def repl(matchobj):
     return ''.join(i for i in matchobj.groups() if i)
print re.sub(r"(-?)(?:\b0+(\.\d)(\d*)(?<!-0\.0)(?<!0\.0)\b|\b([1-9]\d*)\.0+\b)|-?(0)+\.0\b", repl , x)
```

Output:

`0
0
.12
-.12
1
12
-12
12.001
-12.001
10.01
-10.01
.12`

Comment: Why is there a space in the first line of output?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 any reason for downvoting or its still the revenge mode

Comment: I did not downvote it, but I think I know why it was downvoted. The OP asked how to reduce the size of rounded _floating point numbers_. Your solution works with a _character string_ that happens to have _several_ character representations of floating point numbers. You solve a different problem, and much of your RE's complexity is due to parsing the string.

Comment: @DYZ i dont get u....ur solution and my solution does the same thing...

Comment: The result is the same, but the input is different. Your `x` is a concatenated string representation of all of the OP's numeric values. To build `x`, one must do `' '.join(str(n) for n in numbers)` - and then your RE breaks it down into individual fragments again, repairs each fragment, and concatenates one more time. What's the point?

Comment: Actually this is easier to utilize in my case, works perfect

Comment: @DYZ u dont need to join...u can use indivisually as well....i just posted in this manner

Comment: Numbers like `1.4400000` --> `1.440000` instead of `1.44`

Comment: Hard to know. @Denis is a regular poster on blender.stackexchange and a similar post re obj export came up re stripping leading and  trailing zeros.  If it's not too difficult to implement would be, IMO, a good edit. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228273/remove-extra-digits-in-obj-file-export/228287#228287

Comment: @batFINGER I needed to reduce the number of characters in a text file because of limitations of file size.

Comment: wow !!!!!!!! after 5 years everybody is back!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to shrink your numbers at the character level. Use regular expressions:

```
if n == 0: # Takes care of 0.0, -0.0, 0000.000, etc.
  m = "0"
elif type(n) == int: # Takes care of integer numbers
    m = re.sub(r'^(-)?0+', r'\1', str(n))
elif n > 0: # Takes care of fp positive numbers
    m = re.sub(r'^0+|\.?0+$', '', str(n))
else: # Takes care of fp negative numbers, DIY
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [360]: alist=[0.0, -0.0, .12, -.12, 1.0]
```

General float formatting in the Py3 style `format`:

```
In [361]: '{}, {}, {}, {}, {}'.format(*alist)
Out[361]: '0.0, -0.0, 0.12, -0.12, 1.0'
```

The `n` (or `g`) format gets part way to where you want:

```
In [362]: '{:n}, {:n}, {:n}, {:n}, {:n}'.format(*alist)
Out[362]: '0, -0, 0.12, -0.12, 1'
```

It still includes the leading `0` for `0.12`.

Comment: If it still includes the leading `0` for floats between `0` and `1`, isn't it inadequate?

Comment: `-0` looks kinda wicked.

Comment: Is it worth removing that leading 0?  Better to use defined formatting tools than to pass the values through obscure regex expressions to save a character or two.

Comment: Saving a character or two seems to be the entire point, though.